# I am getting an error in my terminal lias command not found

Tags: bash, terminal, localhost, alias, listen

Whenever I open my terminal I always get this error **bash: lias: command not found**. I though of ignoring it but I am not able to listen on localhost:3000. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEvdH.png)

Please help me fix this

Comment: Just guess, you have an `alias` entry in your shellrc files, and the leading `a` was remove one way or the other...

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre]? See [ask] for further guidance. Can you please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text? [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See [/editing-help#code](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

@MayankRaman based on @Jetchisel explanation - which I totally agree with - here I'll try to provide some hints that I wish will help you to better understand the reason and find the problematic file.

Assuming you are using [Git Bash](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/what-is-git-bash), which provides Git command-line shell, to make some aliases permanent (think about a command shortcut when talking about `alias`) you have to store it in the relevant file(s) to make it permanent - these files are called initialization files for a `shell`.

Initialization files may be in both User's `$HOME` directory (for each individual User configuration) or somewhere in the `/etc` directory (to be implemented for all Users).

Now you need to figure out in which of your initialization files you have the **wrong** line `lias` (instead of `alias <followed by a defined command shortcut>` ).

The simplest way I can suggest starting with is the following commands, which will try to `grep` (filter) the `lias` string in the files in your User's `$HOME` and `/etc` directories and IF found one, then **outputs** the file name and line number so you can fix it by commenting out or removing or fixing the relevant line.

*Note: Run and analyze these commands one at a time*

- `find "${HOME}" -maxdepth 1 \( ! -name '.bash_history' \) -type f -exec /bin/bash -c 'grep -nw "lias"  $1 2>/dev/null && echo "Found in: $1"' _ {} \;`
- `find "/etc" -maxdepth 2 -type f -exec /bin/bash -c 'grep -nw "lias"  $1 2>/dev/null && echo "Found in: $1"' _ {} \;`

Since I don't have a wrong `lias` parameter, below you may see an example output of the same command that found `alias` (instead of `lias) in my` /etc/profile.d/aliases.sh` file:

```
5:alias ls='ls -F --color=auto --show-control-chars'
6:alias ll='ls -l'
18:             alias $name="winpty $name.exe"
Found in: /etc/profile.d/aliases.sh
```

---

PS. These commands have been tested in

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.23(2)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```